# How to convert Longbuffer to double?

Tags: java, android, encryption

```
LongBuffer i2;
double k0;

c =  (long) Math.pow(i2, k0);
```

---

i have this formula in my code which involves encryption. Its an app which encrypts SMS before sending, and decyrpts the received messages in receivers phone. Since the SMS is in string format,I've converted the string to longbuffer so that it could be encrypted. The problem is one the formula can't parse the longbuffer and double. So how to convert longbuffer to double?

Answer (score 0):

```
long n = i2.get(0);
double x = n;
double y = Double.longBitsToDouble(n);
```

You need to get the data from the buffer.

Use `x` above. The variant where the long in the LongBuffer actually is a binary double (quiote unlikely) is covered with `y`.

In general search for `LongBuffer` and inspect the API from the javadoc.